# Satellite signature of reindeer carcasses

Tags: satellite, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, sentinel-2

In a recent incident (august 2016) in the Norwegian mountains 322 [reindeer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reindeer) (*rangifer tarandus*) [were killed by lightning](http://reut.rs/2bUE8nB). The carcasses position are documented, although only by point data and not polygons. No vertical photos exist as yet. The carcasses will be left to decay. Heads were removed to do studies on the potential presence of [chronic wasting disease](http://www.mattilsynet.no/language/english/animals/chronic_wasting_disease_found_in_a_wild_reindeer_in_norway.22242) in Norway.

Given that we get good vertical imagery for the actual area and some of the surrounding area, I imagine we will have a good point of reference to use the incidence to learn about other similar incidences should they occur. The rangers might not always have time, resources or be lucky enough to find such incidences.

I imagine that indicators of such instances could be change in vegetation due to bird droppings and nutrients in the ground due to carcasses.

I am thinking that researchers might use this incidence for a study where one looks at the possibility to:

- find indicators of similar incidences using satellite imagery (by
  current signature)
- find historical incidences by learning how such an incidence changes the vegetation

Would securing drone photos give us a good point of reference for future studies?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how you thought this could work? I can't see satellite imagery giving you much to go on. Even 30cm imagery (assuming you were able to acquire it for a large-enough area for the right time scale(s)) isn't going to be a lot of use for an individual carcass. Something like Sentinel-2 has nothing like enough resolution.

Comment: The principle of satellite imagery for this purpose is not to "see" the individual carcass, but to consider if the signature for a measured area (10x10 m or greater) can give an indication smaller occurrences. Some more background here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264629913_Applications_of_Very_High-Resolution_Imagery_in_the_Study_and_Conservation_of_Large_Predators_in_the_Southern_Ocean

Comment: I think you need to refine your question with more detail on what you are trying to do here. Basically, what is the question? The "how should I proceed" is probably too vague to get a useable answer without more specific context.

Answer (score 3):

I had a look at Sentinel imagery. The S2 images are too cloudy, as you can check [here](http://apps.sentinel-hub.com/sentinel-playground/#x=8.050231933593752%2By=60.01683463398483%2Bs=11%2Bpreset=1_NATURAL_COLOR%2Blayers=1_NATURAL_COLOR%2Bmaxcc=100%2Bgain=1%2Btime=2015-01-01/2016-08-29%2Bpriority=mostRecent).

And with S1 there is an image on 27/8 (the day after the lightning) and another one with similar characteristics on 22/8 so I made the difference between both images but I could see nothing but speckle noise in the area.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/492cd038d1bc48c669561386aa10dfa5